# Apache process level stickiness

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, sticky

In apache server can we have the process level stickiness, without havinbg to used the daemon mode?
With mod_balancer module we can have stickiness at server level , i want all my request to go to the exactly same process on that server. Is is possible? or what can be the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can balance apache mod_wsgi with some parameters. It can load a single process for interpreter and you can choose how many thread per process. Also you can have for a single virtual host resources you need.
[WSGIDaemonProcess](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess)

Comment: They were asking whether if it can be done without daemon mode. And the answer to that is effectively no, unless you run many instances of Apache each with a single child process and then use a front end which supports stick routing.